Can we use scanf in the test bench?
I've made a design using Vitis HLS 2022.2. I use scanf and print functions in the testbench file, the printf works fine but while using scanf the C simulation doesn't terminate and gets frozen at "generating csim.exe".
Could someone explain to me what the issue is? Isn't it possible to use scanf even in the testbench file?

You cannot have scanf statements in the code you feed Vitis. It has to have all the variables set at compile time to generate the bitstream. If you are trying to configure a set of variables inside your program, try including the values in a header file or if possible try to assign your variables within the program.
